# memory leak in Java when it should not happen

Tags: java, memory

I've added this piece of code to my program recently and now it seems to crash because it runs out of memory.

**This is what I've observed:**

While executing this piece of code for multiple times (1000 times.)
the memory will double or even triple. When I manually hint the Garbage collector it does not seem to decrease the amount.

**My code**

```
public void updateServers() {
    Servers servers = new Servers();
    GameDAO gameDAO = new GameDAO();
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> lastList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> playersList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> premiumList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> scoreList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.gamesPOJOS = gameDAO.getGames();
    for (GamesPOJO gamesPOJO : gamesPOJOS) {
        CachedServerPOJO lastUpdated = new CachedServerPOJO(servers.getServers("last", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        CachedServerPOJO score = new CachedServerPOJO(servers.getServers("score", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        CachedServerPOJO players = new CachedServerPOJO(servers.getServers("players", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        CachedServerPOJO premium = new CachedServerPOJO(servers.getServers("premium", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        lastList.add(lastUpdated);
        playersList.add(players);
        premiumList.add(premium);
        scoreList.add(score);
        System.out.println("Updated all servers on homepage");
    }
    this.lastUpdatedServers = lastList;
    this.serversBasedOnPlayers = playersList;
    this.serversBasedOnPremium = premiumList;
    this.serversBasedOnScore = scoreList;
}
```

My asumption is that `servers` and `gameDAO` will be removed after this piece of code has ran. And that the previous reverence to the heap for `lastUpdatedServers` etc will be removed.
This way the memory should not increase.
However it still does. 
Either I missed out something or I've made a wrong assumption.

I hope I supplied enough information if not, let me know and I'll add in more.

**EDIT:**

What I've found so far is that the problem might be because it is accessed from a static context. And my assumptions are that static objects don't get removed from memory even if they are no longer referenced.

This is some code I'm using:
**The updating method that should update all values.**
this will run every 1 minute to update the arraylists.

```
 private static Servers serversClass = new Servers();
private static GameDAO gameDAO = new GameDAO();
public static void updateServers() {
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> lastList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> playersList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> premiumList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CachedServerPOJO> scoreList = new ArrayList<>();
    votingSite.setGamesPOJOS(gameDAO.getGames());
    for (GamesPOJO gamesPOJO : votingSite.getGamesPOJOS()) {
        CachedServerPOJO lastUpdated = new CachedServerPOJO(serversClass.getServers("last", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        CachedServerPOJO score = new CachedServerPOJO(serversClass.getServers("score", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        CachedServerPOJO players = new CachedServerPOJO(serversClass.getServers("players", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        CachedServerPOJO premium = new CachedServerPOJO(serversClass.getServers("premium", gamesPOJO.getName()), gamesPOJO.getName());
        lastList.add(lastUpdated);
        playersList.add(players);
        premiumList.add(premium);
        scoreList.add(score);
        System.out.println("Updated all servers on homepage");
    }
    votingSite.setLastUpdatedServers(lastList);
    votingSite.setServersBasedOnPlayers(playersList);
    votingSite.setServersBasedOnPremium(premiumList);
    votingSite.setServersBasedOnScore(scoreList);
}
```

**How the values are used**

```
serversPOJOS = votingSite.getLastUpdatedServers().stream().filter(x -> x.getGameName().equalsIgnoreCase(game)).findFirst().orElse(null).getServersPOJOS();
```

**How the method `updateServers()` is used**
this is one place it is being run. it is also being run in a runnable with `Weblistener.updateServers();`

```
    public static VotingSite getVotingSite() {
    if (votingSite == null) {
        votingSite = new VotingSite();
        updateServers();
    }
    return votingSite;
}
```

Are my assumptions right? and what would be a suitable solution to fix my problem.?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting a memory dump? That should show you what types of objects were most common in memory at the time, so you can narrow down your search.

Comment: I have not, How would i do that, I've never done it before.
The Application is being run on a tomcat 9.0.2 server

Comment: Check out one of these perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385088/tracking-memory-usage-in-a-tomcat-webapp

Comment: Just because you are creating all the objects in the method does not mean all the memory they use will be be garbage collected at some point after the method is done. For example the `CachedServerPOJO` can initialize some static variables with strong references. We cant really tell. My advice is to memory profile your app with tools like YourKit.

Comment: I will now try to profile the application, i will get back with my results when i figgure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem for me.

I forgot a `preparedStatement.close();`
in on of the methods that got called by the `updateServers();`

So the prepared statement would always stay opend and the memory would increase. since I've added the close the memmory seems to be at a stead rate.
[Memory graph after adding `preparedStatement.close();`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAD8O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are only true partly.

When you leave the method the named variables are *eligible* for garbage collection. As long as the upper limit for garbage collection is not reached no garbage collection is performed. Gabarge collection is only performed if the memory is exhausted.

Also it is possible that you create strong static references in your classes (which we cannot see) that inhibits the garbage collection, e.g.:

```
public class Servers {
    private static Servers servers;
    public Servers() {
        servers = new Servers(); // or this or ...
    }
}
```

Please note that the code written by me is only to show the problem. This code should not be used as long as you do not know what happens...

Also it is possible that you create resources inside the classes which inhibit also the release (e.g. database connections).

So use a memory profiler and check the memory usage with this.

The oracle JDK comes with a profiler called `jvisualvm`. This can help you but it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: In the Servers class i call a static function for a database connection. I will try to get to understand the profiler to further understand the problem.

`private MysqlConnection mysqlConnection = VotingSite.getMysqlConnection;`
And VotingSite will return a Connection Object if it has already been created and if not it will create a new one.

Comment: If i used the tool right, it seems that there are many instances of `byte[]` and of `com.mysql.jdbc.field` And i'm not quite understanding why it is doing it because in my own code i've never used a byte array. atleast not in the path it is taking while running that method.

Comment: I've added some more informaton to my post. and what I have concluded thus far.